# Why do we still need to implement 'noArgsConstructor' if Java gives a non-parameterized constructor by default?

Tags: java, spring-boot, pojo, default-constructor, parameterized-constructor

In Spring boot if we are creating a POJO class and we end up creating only a parameterized constructor and not any default constructor then Java will throw errors, why does this happen if Java provides a non-parameterized constructor by default why do I still have to implement it manually?

I tried not creating a non-parameterized constructor for a POJO and it threw an error when I created an object of the POJO class in another class.

Comment: Maybe you wanna show us the class which throws the error? Bear in mind that Java only provides an implicit defualt NoArg Constructor as long as there are no other construcators implemented. As soon as you provide a constructor for eg field instantiation there is no longer a NoArg constructor provided.

Comment: Can you clarify whether "not creating only parameterized constructor and not any default constructor" means that you are not declaring any constructor?

Comment: @tgdavies sorry, mistake corrected.

Comment: @Slevin I created a simple class named 'Employee'. It has 3 fields, now apart from that I have parameterized constructor and getters and setters for all the fields. Now if I try to make an object of the Employee class using new keyword, it will show error saying it expects 3 parameters and If I gave provide that the error will go as I already have parameterized constructor. Now I can also remove the error by implemeting a non-parameterized constructor, that means Java is not providing a default constructor by its own isn't it.

Comment: Can you share the error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java, if you don't provide any constructor explicitly in your class, Java provides a default constructor. However, there's an exception to this rule. If you define any constructor explicitly in your class, Java won't provide a default constructor for you.

```
public class Employee{
    // No constructor defined explicitly

    // Other class members and methods
}
```

In this case, since no constructor is explicitly defined, Java will provide a default constructor for the Employee class.

However, if you define any constructor in your class, then Java won't provide a default constructor. For example:

```
public class Employee{
    String name;
    public Employee(String name) {
        // Constructor with parameter
    }

    // Other class members and methods
}
```

In this case, since a constructor is explicitly defined (Employee(String x)), Java won't provide a default constructor for Employee. If you need a default constructor along with your parameterized constructor, you'll need to define it explicitly:

```
public class Employee{
    String x
    public Employee(String name) {
        // Constructor with parameter
    }

    public Employee() {
        // Default constructor
    }

    // Other class members and methods
}
```

Now, the Employee has both a parameterized constructor and a default constructor.

Answer (score 5):

Because it literally works this way.

Excerpt from [Java specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.9):

> **If** a class contains **no** constructor declarations, **then** a default constructor is **implicitly** declared.

For clarity

**If** a class contains **any** constructor declarations, **then** a default constructor is **not** declared.

Comment: I created a simple class named 'Employee'. It has 3 fields, now apart from that I have parameterized constructor and getters and setters for all the fields. Now if I try to make an object of the Employee class using new keyword, it will show error saying it expects 3 parameters and If I gave provide that the error will go as I already have parameterized constructor. Now I can also remove the error by implemeting a non-parameterized constructor, that means Java is not providing a default constructor by its own isn't it.

Comment: @AnanthuKKumar, It will give a default constructor if and only if No constructor is defined in your class. Otherwise[If you already created a constructor as your case,] you should provide an implemenation for no args constructor

Answer (score 0):

In Java, when you create a class and don't explicitly define any constructors, Java provides a default no-argument constructor for you. This default constructor initializes member variables to their default values.

However, when you explicitly define a constructor in your class—whether it's a parameterized constructor or any other constructor—Java does not provide the default constructor anymore. If you want to use a no-argument constructor after defining any other constructors, you need to explicitly define it yourself. Java assumes that you are taking control over object initialization, and thus, it won't automatically generate a default constructor for you.